# How to prevent a list from scrolling horizontally

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I have created a list using a block element contained in a view. When the block contains enough items, I am able to scroll vertically as intended.

The problem here is that, even if the block does not overflow vertically or horizontally, I am also able to scroll horizontally. This is illustrated in the following pictures:

Normal operation:

[image: Normal operation]

Scrolled horizontally:

[image: Scrolled horizontally]

Here is the ACSS for the containing view:

```
position: absolute;
top: 378rpx;
width: 750rpx;
```

Is there any way to constrict the block from scrolling horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that a higher-order view accidentally had a width that was more than 750rpx and this allowed scrolling to the side.

Fixing that made that the list stays in the same place horizontally.